# How to call function stored in string variable? [PHP]

Tags: php, drupal

I have a question for the experts in PHP. Well, I have data in the variable $ rows, in which I have included the source code for several functions such as:

```
$ rows = "
gmap3_tools_create_marker (21.445985, 74.521431, 'marker with info window', '<a href=http://www.google.com> www.google.com </ a> some text some text photos.') 
gmap3_tools_create_marker (22.445985, 73.521431, 'marker with info window', '<a href=http://www.google.com> www.google.com </ a> some text some text photos.') 
gmap3_tools_create_marker (23.445985, 75.521431, 'marker with info window', '<a href=http://www.google.com> www.google.com </ a> some text some text photos.') "
```

This is a result of the use of Views in Drupal: generates an entry that using views-view.tpl.php I edit the location by placing the result in the variable $ rows in the code necessary gmap3-tools.
This string is an array of object markers necessary for applying the Function gmap3_tools_add_map markers.

```
gmap3_tools_add_map(array(
'mapId' => 'gmap-canvas',
'mapOptions' => array(
  'zoom' => 15,
  'center'=>'51.745985, 15.598451',
),
'markers' => array($rows),
'gmap3ToolsOptions' => array(
  'defaultMarkersPosition' => GMAP3_TOOLS_DEFAULT_MARKERS_POSITION_CENTER,
),
'markerOptions' => array(
  // Set custom shadow for all icons.
  'shadow' => file_create_url(drupal_get_path('module', 'gmap3_tools') . '/images/druplicon-shadow.png'),
),
));
```

Of course, the above code does not work. But if you will paste was directly the result (that which is above) to the function instead of a string variable $ rows is a function gmap3_tools_add_map nicely applied markers.

I know that the problem lies in the fact that it does not perform the functions gmap3_tools_create_marker they are sent as a string.

Is it possible to convert a string to function?

I tried the eval function but to no avail. I thought about call_user_func but unfortunately I do not know how to bite, please help.

**The code must be called exactly in this array.** I can not give the result (by eval) only directly same function in the array, and also not as a variable.

I did so: 
    $ pieces = explode ('),', $ rows); 
    $ pieces [0] = $ pieces [0]. ') ";

```
'markers' => array ($ pieces [0]) <- do not display
```

Another example did not work 
    foreach ($ pieces as $ f) {
        $ markers [] = eval ("return $ f;"); 
    } 
    'Markers' => array ($ markers)

On the other hand pasting the code directly into an array like this, everything is displayed correctly.

```
'markers' => array (
gmap3_tools_create_marker (21.343556, 35.532361, 'Some text', '<a href="www.somesite.com"> some site </ a> <br> Some text'),
```

Please help.

Comment: Is there anything that stops you from splitting that string(regex) and giving the arguments to `call_user_func_array`?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the call_user_func function.

```
call_user_func("gmap3_tools_create_marker", param1, param2 param3);
```

If you are really set against parsing the values properly, you can use Eval.  This is frowned upon and potentially dangerous so again consider finding a better solution.

```
eval($rows);
```

eval will execute the code in a given string.

Comment: Cheruvian but i have this function stored in var $rows ... I want inpunt this code to other but not as string.

Comment: I don't understand your comment but if you want to run it literally... use eval

Comment: you can still split the string in `$rows` and use `call_user_func`. If `eval()` is the answer of your question, then your question is most probably wrong

Answer (score 0):

Aside from trying to parse that into something meaningful, you could do something with `eval`:

```
$funcs = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode("\n", $rows)));

foreach($funcs as $f) {
    $markers[] = eval("return $f;");
}
```

Then just use:

```
'markers' => $markers,
```

If you could define it as an array at the start then you could omit the first part:

```
$rows = array(
"gmap3_tools_create_marker (21.445985, 74.521431, 'marker with info window', '<a href=http://www.google.com> www.google.com </ a> some text some text photos.')",
"gmap3_tools_create_marker (22.445985, 73.521431, 'marker with info window', '<a href=http://www.google.com> www.google.com </ a> some text some text photos.')",
"gmap3_tools_create_marker (23.445985, 75.521431, 'marker with info window', '<a href=http://www.google.com> www.google.com </ a> some text some text photos.')",
);
```

Comment: On the other hand pasting the code directly into an array like this, everything is displayed correctly. 

'markers' => array (
gmap3_tools_create_marker (21.343556, 35.532361, 'Some text', '<a href="www.somesite.com"> some site </ a> <br> Some text'), 

Please help.

Comment: The code must be called exactly in this array. I can not give the result (by eval) only directly same function in the array, and also not as a variable.